# Hiding path information in Dot net error page and IIS error page

Tags: .net, iis

Please let me know how the hide the highlighted information in error pages.

[image: 404 Error]

[image: Serverapplication Error]

Comment: check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it is tough to remove physical path from response context directly. For error like 404, you could set httperror

`<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" />` or

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" />
```

However, for application, you may need to redirect custom .net error.

```
  <customErrors mode="On">
            <error redirect="http://xxxxxxxx" statusCode="500" />
        </customErrors>
```